# Can't get RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter USB 3.0 working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet

I am striving to get a RTL8153 working.
I can see it as a USB:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13fe:6300 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Silicon-Power16G
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:0250 Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can see the module is loaded, but not used:

```
~$ lsmod | grep r8152
r8152                  77824  0
mii                    20480  1 r8152
```

I can see the hardware listed:

```
~$ lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:3.3
       logical name: enx4ce173421ae9
       serial: 4c:e1:73:42:1a:e9
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=half firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

I can see the interface configuration:

```
~$ ifconfig
enx4ce173421ae9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 4c:e1:73:42:1a:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I can't bring the interface up:

```
~$ sudo ip link set enx4ce173421ae9 up
menks@vivo:~$ ip -br -c link show
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
wlo1             UP             bc:17:b8:14:53:bb <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enx4ce173421ae9  DOWN           4c:e1:73:42:1a:e9 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
```

I can see that it is missconfigured:

```
$ resolvectl status
Link 4 (enx4ce173421ae9)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

Any clue about how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

It looks like the interface is coming up at only 10Mbit/s, which might indicate a cabling problem, or a problem with a hub/switch/router. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables?

**Update #1**: replacing the ethernet cable fixed the problem.